# how to replace div content for button click on same page in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like to show div content by 4 different button click on same page by replacing or hiding previous button click div content...
code-

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" style="padding-top:12px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn1">Btn1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn2">Btn2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn3">Btn3</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn4">Btn4</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="pilot" style="display:block;">
   <p>Name1</p>
   <h4>my name is A..........</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="design" style="display:block;">
   <p>Name2</p>
   <h4>my name is A..........</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="instrument" style="display:block;">
   <p>Name3</p>
   <h4>my name is A..........</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="innovations" style="display:block;">
   <p>Name4</p>
   <h4>my name is A..........</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried two jquery scripts but not worked as per my requirement...
script1-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#design").css("display","none");
    $("#instrument").css("display","none");
    $("#innovations").css("display","none");
    $("#pilot").css("display","block");
    }

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#pilot").css("display","none");
    $("#instrument").css("display","none");
    $("#innovations").css("display","none");
    $("#design").css("display","block");
    }

$("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("#design").css("display","none");
    $("#pilot").css("display","none");
    $("#innovations").css("display","none");
    $("#instrument").css("display","block");
    }

$("#btn4").click(function(){
    $("#design").css("display","none");
    $("#instrument").css("display","none");
    $("#pilot").css("display","none");
    $("#innovations").css("display","block");
    }
}
```

script2-

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#design").replaceWith( $("#pilot").show() );
    $("#instrument").replaceWith( $("#pilot").show() );
    $("#innovations").replaceWith( $("#pilot").show() );
    }

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#pilot").replaceWith( $("#design").show() );
    $("#instrument").replaceWith( $("#design").show() );
    $("#innovations").replaceWith( $("#design").show() );
    }

$("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("#design").replaceWith( $("#instrument").show() );
    $("#pilot").replaceWith( $("#instrument").show() );
    $("#innovations").replaceWith( $("#instrument").show() );
   }

$("#btn4").click(function(){
    $("#design").replaceWith( $("#innovations").show() );
    $("#instrument").replaceWith( $("#innovations").show() );
    $("#pilot").replaceWith( $("#innovations").show() );
    }
}
</script>
```

so please give me some suitable answer to workout ....if it is possible with bootstrap scrollspy then also suggest....tnx

Comment: Did you include jQuery library?

Comment: yes....<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you have to close your click events - after `}` you have to have `);`. Example: `$("#btn1").click(function() { your code });`

Comment: tnx dear....these silly mistakes really ruined me....as i am new to web development, this happened....ok my first script working nicely now...tnx 1ns again...

Comment: I recommend you to code at codepen.io for example, you will be able to see JavaScript errors with ease.

Answer (score 4):

Your first code example doesn't work as you haven't closed the braces and brackets correctly. Here's a working version: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qhkpsoap/1/). Your second code example is using an entirely wrong approach.

That being said, by using DRY principles you can massively reduce the amount of JS code required to achieve this.

Firstly, add a `data-*` attribute to your `.btn` elements which can be used to identify the `div` to be shown when the button is clicked:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn1" data-target="pilot">Btn1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn2" data-target="design">Btn2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn3" data-target="instrument">Btn3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn4" data-target="innovations">Btn4</button>
```

Then in your JS code you can write a single click handler which works for all buttons:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#content div').hide();
    var target = '#' + $(this).data('target');
    $(target).show();
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qhkpsoap/)

Answer (score 0):

Associate the target div's with the buttons using data-attributes. Now, on every click you can get the target value from that data-attribute and then use that to select only that div, that you need to show. You should hide all div's before showing the one that needs to be shown.

```
<a id="btn1" href="#" data-target="design">button 1</a>
<a id="btn2" href="#" data-target="pilot">button 2</a>
<a id="btn3" href="#" data-target="instrument">button 3</a>

<div id="design-div" class="targetdivs">Design</div>
<div id="pilot-div" class="targetdivs">Pilot</div>
<div id="instrument-div" class="targetdivs">Instrument</div>


<script>
  $("#btn1, #btn2, #btn3").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(".targetdivs").css("display", "none");
    $("#"+target+"-div").css("display", "block");
  });//click
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
     $("#content div").hide()
     $("#pilot").show()
});

 $('#btn2').click(function(){
     $("#content div").hide()
     $("#design").show()
});
 $('#btn3').click(function(){
     $("#content div").hide()
     $("#instrument").show()
});
 $('#btn4').click(function(){
     $("#content div").hide()
     $("#innovations").show()
});
```

here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/Lzh0tcon/)